# covert from base64 to image using c# in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

Any executable funtion to convert from base64 to an image using c# windows 8.1************* . 
I tried :

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    Image returnImage = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
    {
       returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
 return returnImage;
}
```

FromStream not suitable for windows 8.1

Comment: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image does not contain a definition for 'FromStream'

Comment: So how do you expect it to work? Look at the docs for that type and see what methods you have.

Comment: @leppie i looked to most docs and i didn't reach what i need so i posted this question

Comment: See the docs! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx#using_a_stream There is an example there.

Comment: @leppie: the examples there assume you are reading the data from a file. They don't address the crux of the question here, which is how to deal with a `byte[]` object, convert it to a stream, and initialize a bitmap from that. Yes, those examples show the initialization from a stream, but not in a way that fully answers this question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: The link shows how to deal with a stream, the OP is already doing the conversion from `byte[]`

Comment: @leppie: "the OP is already doing the conversion from byte[]" -- unfortunately, no. Not in a way that is compatible with the needs of the `BitmapImage` class the OP needs to use on WinRT. The regular `MemoryStream` object doesn't work in that context.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Sorry, I dont know WinRT much and did not realise the incompatibility. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image` class is a *control* object, not an actual bitmap-type object. What you actually want is a `BitmapImage`. Of course, given this misunderstanding, you're likely to run into other problems with your code; you don't show the caller of this method, but if you've confused the type here, you've probably confused it elsewhere. So that will have to be fixed.

Secondly, as is the case with many things in WinRT, doing what you want is somewhat more complicated than if you were using the desktop API. :(

That said, something like this should work:

```
public Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(byteArrayIn.AsBuffer(0, byteArrayIn.Length));
        stream.Seek(0);

        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

        await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);

        return image;
    }
}
```

Then you can set that object to the `Source` property of an `Image` control object.

Some notes:

1. In your original example, disposing the source stream is at the very least unconventional. My recollection is that in at least some cases, doing so isn't legal, as the `Bitmap` object returned requires the `Stream` instance to remain undisposed. For WinRT, AFAIK disposing the stream *after* the bitmap has been initialized is fine.
2. The `AsBuffer()` method is an extension method. You'll need to include a `using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;` in your code if it's not already there for it to work.

See also:

- [BitmapSource class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx)
- [InMemoryRandomAccessStream class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.aspx)
- [WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.windowsruntimebufferextensions(v=vs.105).aspx)